# My span selected isn't updated as expected

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am coding along with a course and the H1 is supposed to update the RGB to the selected pickedColor but isn't updating, I'm not sure where my error is. In my JS page I was expecting when I coded "colorDisplay.textContent = pickedColor;:" for it to work. Thanks!

```js
         var colors = [
             "rgb(255, 0, 0)",
             "rgb(255, 255, 0)",
             "rgb(0, 255, 0)",
             "rgb(0, 255, 255)",
             "rgb(0, 0, 255)",
             "rgb(255, 0, 255)",
          ]

         var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
         var pickedColor = colors[3];
         var colorDisplay = document.getElementById("colorDisplay");

          colorDisplay.textConent = pickedColor;


          for(var i = 0; i <squares.length; i++){
             squares[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
          }
```

```css
body {
            background-color: #232323;
          }

         .square {
            width: 30%;
            background: purple;
            padding-bottom: 30%;
            float: left;
            margin: 1.66%;
          }

          #container {
            margin: 0 auto;
            max-width: 600px;
          }

          h1 {
              color: white;
    
          }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <title>Colour Game</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="colorGame.css">
         </head>
         <body>

            <h1>The Great <span id="colorDisplay">RGB</span> Colour Game</h1>
             <div id="container">
                <div class="square"></div>
                <div class="square"></div>
                <div class="square"></div>
                <div class="square"></div>
                <div class="square"></div>
                <div class="square"></div>
            </div>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="colorGame.js"></script>
         </body>
         </html>
```

Comment: There is answer that's been given, but also, assuming that you've been following instructions, there is a spelling mistake...... textContent not textconent

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the style.color option of your element. textContent just sets the text not color.

```js
var colors = [
             "rgb(255, 0, 0)",
             "rgb(255, 255, 0)",
             "rgb(0, 255, 0)",
             "rgb(0, 255, 255)",
             "rgb(0, 0, 255)",
             "rgb(255, 0, 255)",
          ]

         var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
         var pickedColor = colors[3];
         var colorDisplay = document.getElementById("colorDisplay");
   
          colorDisplay.style.color = pickedColor;


          for(var i = 0; i <squares.length; i++){
             squares[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
          }
```

```css
body {
            background-color: #232323;
          }

         .square {
            width: 30%;
            background: purple;
            padding-bottom: 30%;
            float: left;
            margin: 1.66%;
          }

          #container {
            margin: 0 auto;
            max-width: 600px;
          }

          h1 {
              color: white;
    
          }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <title>Colour Game</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="colorGame.css">
         </head>
         <body>

            <h1>The Great <span id="colorDisplay">RGB</span> Colour Game</h1>
             <div id="container">
                <div class="square"></div>
                <div class="square"></div>
                <div class="square"></div>
                <div class="square"></div>
                <div class="square"></div>
                <div class="square"></div>
            </div>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="colorGame.js"></script>
         </body>
         </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need change to use `innerText` as  `colorDisplay.innerText = pickedColor;`

To implement click event to square you can handle as

```
squares.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', event => {
    var colorDisplay = document.getElementById("colorDisplay");
    colorDisplay.innerText = el.style.backgroundColor;
}));
```

```js
var colors = [
             "rgb(255, 0, 0)",
             "rgb(255, 255, 0)",
             "rgb(0, 255, 0)",
             "rgb(0, 255, 255)",
             "rgb(0, 0, 255)",
             "rgb(255, 0, 255)",
          ]

         var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
         var pickedColor = colors[3];
         var colorDisplay = document.getElementById("colorDisplay");

          colorDisplay.innerText = pickedColor;

 for(var i = 0; i <squares.length; i++){
             squares[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
          }

squares.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', event => {
    var colorDisplay = document.getElementById("colorDisplay");
    colorDisplay.innerText = el.style.backgroundColor;
}));
```

```css
body {
            background-color: #232323;
          }

         .square {
            width: 30%;
            background: purple;
            padding-bottom: 30%;
            float: left;
            margin: 1.66%;
          }

          #container {
            margin: 0 auto;
            max-width: 600px;
          }

          h1 {
              color: white;
    
          }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <title>Colour Game</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="colorGame.css">
         </head>
         <body>

            <h1>The Great <span id="colorDisplay">RGB</span> Colour Game</h1>
             <div id="container">
                <div class="square"></div>
                <div class="square"></div>
                <div class="square"></div>
                <div class="square"></div>
                <div class="square"></div>
                <div class="square"></div>
            </div>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="colorGame.js"></script>
         </body>
         </html>
```

Comment: or you know, fix the typo with textContent

Comment: I also help him add event when click to square to get color

Answer (score 0):

You have to add event listeners to the `squres` and update the span color from there.

```js
var colors = [
             "rgb(255, 0, 0)",
             "rgb(255, 255, 0)",
             "rgb(0, 255, 0)",
             "rgb(0, 255, 255)",
             "rgb(0, 0, 255)",
             "rgb(255, 0, 255)",
          ]

         var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
         var pickedColor = colors[4];
         var colorDisplay = document.getElementById("colorDisplay");

          colorDisplay.style.color = pickedColor;


          for(var i = 0; i <squares.length; i++){
             squares[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
          }
          
          for (let node of squares)
            node.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
              colorDisplay.style.color =  e.target.style.backgroundColor;  
          })
```

```css
body {
            background-color: #232323;
          }

         .square {
            width: 30%;
            background: purple;
            padding-bottom: 30%;
            float: left;
            margin: 1.66%;
          }

          #container {
            margin: 0 auto;
            max-width: 600px;
          }

          h1 {
              color: white;
    
          }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <title>Colour Game</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="colorGame.css">
         </head>
         <body>

            <h1>The Great <span id="colorDisplay">RGB</span> Colour Game</h1>
             <div id="container">
                <div class="square"></div>
                <div class="square"></div>
                <div class="square"></div>
                <div class="square"></div>
                <div class="square"></div>
                <div class="square"></div>
            </div>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="colorGame.js"></script>
         </body>
         </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**element.textContent = content**
and
**element.style.attribute = value**

statements can be used to achieve the desired result of changing text content and colour.

**Here is the working demo with the suggested changes:**

**HTML: index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Colour Game</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="colorGame.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>The Great <span id="colorDisplay">RGB</span> Colour Game</h1>
        <div id="container">
            <div class="square"></div>
            <div class="square"></div>
            <div class="square"></div>
            <div class="square"></div>
            <div class="square"></div>
            <div class="square"></div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="colorGame.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS: colorGame.css:**

```
body {
    background-color: #232323;
}

.square {
    width: 30%;
    background: purple;
    padding-bottom: 30%;
    float: left;
    margin: 1.66%;
}

#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 600px;
}

h1 {
    color: white;
}
```

**Javascript: colorGame.js:**

```
var colors = [
    "rgb(255, 0, 0)",
    "rgb(255, 255, 0)",
    "rgb(0, 255, 0)",
    "rgb(0, 255, 255)",
    "rgb(0, 0, 255)",
    "rgb(255, 0, 255)",
]

var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square")
var pickedColor = colors[3]
var colorDisplay = document.getElementById("colorDisplay")

// Set text content using element.textContent = value
colorDisplay.textContent = pickedColor

// Set colour using element.style.color = value
colorDisplay.style.color = pickedColor


for(var i = 0; i <squares.length; i++){
    squares[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i]
}
```

**Output:**

[image]